# "Подключение не защищено" после логина через social-auth-app-django

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, oauth2

Есть Django-проект на heroku,настроил авторизацию через Google или VK,используя `social-auth-app-django`.После логина рядом с адресной строкой браузера появляется метка "Подключение не защищено", но я ставлю курсор в адресную строку, нажимаю Enter и тут же страница перезагружается, и появляется уже метка "Безопасное подключение" с информацией о сертификате. Что это такое, можно ли этого избежать, чтобы после логина сразу же было безопасное подключение?